# Why Javascript event running multiple times per click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, dom-events

I wrote a js-class which handles the Ajax-calls when a user clicks on a button. So the user can simply click on open/close and can open/close a entity in my database.

All works fine. The button-icon changes and the popover title and text changes also. The user can click on the buttons again and again and the Ajax does the work and jQuery changes the look - BUT -

When I watch in my debug bar - I see that with every click a additional Ajax call is running. When I click the button 3 times - the same Ajax-call will run 4 times for changing the entity to open/close.

I inspected the handlers. Every time it is only one handler and one `#close-course` element.

I really don't understand why this Ajax calls get more and more with every click!

Here my js-class:

```
'use strict';

import $ from "jquery";

(function (window, $) {

class CourseApp {
    constructor($wrapper) {

        this.$wrapper = $wrapper.find('.js-wrapper');
        this.$body = $wrapper
        this.iconBtn = this.$wrapper.find('a').blur();
        this.$submitCount = 0;

        this.$wrapper.on(
            'click',
            'a',
            this.handleOpenCloseAction.bind(this)
        );
    }

    handleOpenCloseAction(e) {
        let popover = this.$body.find('.popover')

        // prevent popover to close - when open-button is hitted
        popover
            .on('mousedown', '#open-course', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            });

        // prevent popover to close - when open-button is hitted
        popover
            .on('mousedown', '#close-course', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
            });

        // since open-course-link is clicked - open the course and
        // do some action
        popover
            .on(
                'click',
                '#open-course',
                function (e) {
                    const $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
                    let $icon = $btn.find('.icon-lock-open');

                    if (this.$submitCount === 0) {
                        this.$submitCount++;

                        $.ajax({
                            url: $btn.data('open-course-url'),
                            method: 'POST',
                        }).then(function (data) {
                            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
                            this.iconBtn.blur();
                            this.iconBtn.attr('data-content', data);
                            this.iconBtn.attr('data-original-title', 'Kurs schließen');
                            $('.icon-lock').removeClass('icon-lock').addClass('icon-lock-open');
                        }.bind(this))
                        this.$submitCount = 0;
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            )

        // since close-course-link is clicked - close the course and
        // do some action
        popover
            .on(
                'click',
                '#close-course',
                function (e) {
                    const $btn = $(e.currentTarget);
                    if (this.$submitCount === 0) {
                        this.$submitCount++;

                        $.ajax({
                            url: $btn.data('close-course-url'),
                            method: 'POST',
                        }).then(function (data) {
                            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
                            this.iconBtn.blur();
                            this.iconBtn.attr('data-content', data);
                            this.iconBtn.attr('data-original-title', 'Kurs öffnen');
                            $('.icon-lock-open').removeClass('icon-lock-open').addClass('icon-lock');

                        }.bind(this))
                        this.$submitCount = 0;
                    }

                }.bind(this)
            )
    }

}


window.CourseApp = CourseApp;


})(window, jQuery);
```

My html:

```
 <td class="col-1 js-wrapper">
            <a href="#"
               class="btn btn-primary pop"
               data-content="{% if entity.open %} {{ popoverContentClose }} {% else %} {{ popoverContentOpen }} {% endif %}" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus"
               title=""
               data-original-title="{% if entity.open %} Kurs schließen? {% else %} Kurs öffnen? {% endif %}"
               data-placement="left">

                {% if entity.open %}
                    <i class="icon icon-lock-open"></i>
                {% else %}
                    <i class="icon icon-lock"></i>
                {% endif %}
            </a>
        </td>
```

The popover (is in a twig block):

```
 Möchtest du diesen Kurs wirklich schließen? Die Teilnehmer dieses Kurses müssen somit jeden Kurszugang bestätigen.
<br>
<table class='table popover-table mb-0'>
    <tr>
        <td class='pl-0 border-top-0'>
            <a href='#'
               class='btn btn-danger-outline col-md-12 ml-0' id='close-course' data-close-course-url='{{ path('close_course', {'id' : entity.id}) }}'><i class='icon icon-lock'></i>Schließen</a>
        </td>
        <td class='pr-0 border-top-0'>
            <button class='btn btn-primary col-md-12' class='close'
                    data-dismiss='alert'>{{ 'common.close'|trans }}</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check the methods of the first call? My guess is that the first call is made with the OPTIONS method -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: The first call is this:  
const $wrapper = $('body');
const JsApp = new CourseApp($wrapper); 
I guess that's nothing with the OPTIONS method...

Comment: I found out myself! I had to add: $( e.delegateTarget ).remove(); on the end on my handler. Because bootstrap creates a new popover every time I click on the button. And then on all the popovers this event triggers. With every click (no site refresh) query found one more popover for running the method!

Comment: Should I post the solution in my question?